# Raise an event on a shared Observable

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs, observable

In my Angular app, I have a parent component with two child components. I want to share an observable, call it newUploadStarted$, created in the parent component that the two child components and communicate on. The two child components are multiple instances of the same component that, if clicked, trigger a file upload. I want to raise an event on newUploadStarted$ in the child component such that all child events react to it by clearing old messages they might have.

```
export class ReportUploaderComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() newUploadStarted$: Observable<1>;

...
    onChooseBlueReportFile(files: FileList) {
        newUploadStarted$.raiseEvent(1); // Specific number isn't as important as letting the child raise the event on something it did not create.
       
    }
```

To me, this should be something very simple to do, but I'm just not seeing an example of this in a way that makes sense to me. What am I missing?

Thanks,
Woodsman

Comment: You probably want to use a `Subject` instead of an `Observable`. The relevant difference is that the former can multicast to many observers. In using a `Subject`, you can then use `.next(...)` in your child components to raise events.

Comment: @miqh Could you paste that response as an answer so I can give you credit for it? I didn't realize the Observable was essentially a two party queue. However, even if I had one listener, it's not obvious how to raise an event with an Observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [`Subject`](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject) instead of an `Observable` as a communication bus between your parent and children components.

A `Subject` will let you multicast any values across all observers.

```
newUploadStarted$.next();
```

If you find that you need to share the same bus across children of different parents, you may want to consider relocating it to a service.